# Smart fluid javascript navigation helper

Tags: javascript, css, navigation

I am trying to create a javascript algorithm for an `ul` menu that stretches out `li` elements to use the available width (100%).

I was thinking about an algorithm with this flow:

```
1. calculate the entire available with
2. substract the total elements width to see what's left
3. iterate the elements and substract 1px from the left width and assign 
   it to the smallest li until the iterator runs out of width
```

Is this a good approach or will this be too laggy because it could mean a few hundred iterations?

EDIT: The comments/answers provided don't hold a good answer yet, as perhaps one or many a elements hold lengthy text and these shouldn't get any extra length. The problem needs an algoritmic solution as only the smallest element can be accounted the left over pixel after each iteration so the menu is efficiently strectched

UPDATE: For those confused this is the way I want it to stretch:

```
1. A bank has a total bankroll of 100 dollars
2. Jack has a 40% cut, Dennis has 6%, Minny has 1%
3. The bank starts handing out moneyz, 1 dollar each time starting with the
   poorest kid.
4. In the end Jack has 40% while Dennis and Minny have both 30%

Where the cuts stand for the number of characters in a li's child a node
```

Note: I have read a solution in pure css using table display but that really isn't any good as the underlying `<a>` elements don't seem to stretch with the parent element that way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?  You said _an ul menu that stretches out to use the available width_ (sic), but that could be achieved a number of ways.  The easiest would be to add margin or padding to each li element by dividing up the remaining width.  If you had three elements and 400px remaining, 400/(3*2) = 66.6-ish left and right padding for each li.

Comment: Didn't think of that, that's actually a smart solution, if you create an answer I will accept it thanks! Actually that wouldn't work because I have one (or many) a element(s) with a long text so I don't want to add anything to those.. it needs to be algoritmicly set

Comment: It's too bad that flexbox isn't supported in IE, otherwise this would be very straightforward.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Can anyone explain me why "table display" wouldn't do it ?

Comment: Your example is confusing, where do your numbers come from? Are you trying to describe proportional stretching?

Comment: The numbers are the characters inside the li's child a element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do it with a pure css rather than a javascript approach by using the `display: table` property on the `ul` element and `display: table-cell` on the li elements :

See this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/ERsrf/

If you want to force the `li` elements to have the same width, add this property to the `ul` element :

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

Comment: The problem is this only simulates what I want when you put a max-width and min-width on the li nodes and the a elements inside still don't stretch up to match their parent li

Comment: I have updated your fiddle to illustrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ERsrf/1/ as you can see the larger elements get way to large compared to the smaller ones, also the A element inside doesn't cover the li size causing 'voids' in the clickable area

Comment: This is how far I got using table display http://jsfiddle.net/ERsrf/2/ but min and max width are really _static_ helpers obviously

Comment: Seems it brakes for firefox/ie if you set a li element position:relative if add a position absolute secundairy ul (acting as dropdown)

Comment: @user2298943 If you use a display: block on your `a` elements, it works. See : http://jsfiddle.net/ERsrf/7/

Comment: @user2298943 Does this actually do what you want, or is it an easy/acceptable substitute?  I don't have time right now to check if it matches exactly and I'm kind of curious.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be a bit progressive, as it relies on flexbox doing the heavy lifting. [Flexbox is only starting to be supported by IE10](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), so it's likely to be another 5 years before these techniques can be reliably used in a production environment unless you want to ignore support for IE.

The simple solution is to make the `<ul>` a row flexbox and flex all the `<li>` elements equally:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Of course, in practice you'll need to add browser prefixes, so the CSS will bulk up a bit.

[Flexbox fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjTAB/)

Comment: @user2298943, [so would something like this be more appropriate then?](http://jsfiddle.net/jjTAB/2/)

Comment: Yea thats downright perfect, I achieved it as Brewal suggested here http://jsfiddle.net/ERsrf/2/ but of course you dont want max and min width set like that..

Answer (score 1):

Add each element to an array (var elems) of objects like `{ "width": 0, "number": 0, "LIs": [] }`, sort the array by the widths, then get the amount of extra space you have.  After that (pseudo code follows):

```
    if(elems.length > 1) {
        while(extraSpaceLeft > 0) {
            leastWidth = elems object with lowest width;
            secondLeastWidth = elems object with second lowest width;
            toAdd = min(abs(leastWidth - secondLeastWidth),extraSpaceLeft);
            toAdd -= toAdd % leastWidth.number;
            extraSpaceLeft -= toAdd;
            leastWidth += toAdd/leastWidth.number;
            if(leastWidth.width === secondLeastWidth) combine the two objects
            else if(leastWidth.width > secondLeastWidth) swap the two objects in the array
        }
    } else { elems[0].width += extraSpaceLeft; }

    set the element width of each elem based on the elems widths
```

This is really rough pseudo-code, and the logic may not be exactly right, but it should be a lot faster than adding one pixel at a time.

Comment: This is probably the best answer yet