# equals Margins between elements

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs inside another one.

I want inside `divs`to have equals margins between them so there is the same space between left edge of root `div` and first inside `div`, between two inside `div` and between last inside `div`and the right edge of root.

Now i can see this

http://jsfiddle.net/rXYqR/

Is there any way to do this with any specially property of CSS? Or i had to assign margins manually?

Thanks!

Comment: `#root * {margin:inherit;}`? if thats not what you want, try describing it in a less confusing way.

Comment: This sounds like exactly the same question [that was asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964294/how-to-evenly-space-many-inline-block-elements/16964570). It turned out to be a surprisingly difficult question -- we didn't find a good answer that included the margin on the sides as well as between the elements.

Comment: @Spudley down there is a good answer that solve this problem (i think)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#root{
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
    font-size:0;
}

#root > div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: calc((100% - 200px) / 5); /* Pre-calced 40px */
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rXYqR/2/

Comment: Wow! i don't know 'calc' exists! it's great! Thanks!

Comment: It does for all good browsers.  Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9+ all support it.  Safari 6 supports it with a vendor prefix, but it crashes the browser a lot.